# convert huge amount of mp4 videos to audio in short time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, conversion, video-conversion

previously i used to think i can convert say 100G video to audio in matters of seconds because i thought video and audio are seperare in mp4 format and converting video to audio is like doing an easy cut like a scissor.

after complete research i found what i was thinking to was purely false and conversion needs far more time than seconds which is roughly 3 minutes at best for 1 hour video and i have thousands of hours of videos which need to convert and waiting this amount of time is horrible.

do you have any idea about my idea of converting longs videos to audio in matter of seconds like cutting video from audio, is such a thing ever possible? or is there anything near to it so i can convert these long videos in short time?

Comment: Could you add the operating system you use?

Comment: @mashuptwice Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends. MP4 is just a container. A MP4 container contains (mostly) multiple streams of data (audio, video, subtitles, ...). All these streams have their own codec (h.264, MP3, AAC, OGG, ...). You are talking about extracting the audio stream. That should be fast, but you can not change the codec or you have to use a fast one, as reencoding takes a big amount of processing power and time.

You could use `ffmpeg` for modifying audio and video via CLI.
So if your input has AAC audio and you want to tell `ffmpeg` to output MP3 then what `ffmpeg` would do is:

1. extract AAC stream
2. Decode it
3. Encode to MP3 (usually the bottleneck)
4. Write to output file

If you keep the input format so your output would be aac file, ffpmeg can skip points 2 and 3 and it will be much faster.

So:

1. Know your input format (`ffmpeg -i file.mp4`, `ffprobe file.mp4`, or `mediainfo file.mp4`)
2. Keep the format (`ffmpeg -i the-file.mp4 -vn -c:a copy output.{mp3|aac|ogg|wav}`)
3. If point 2 is impossible use raw audio like wav (`ffmpeg -i the-file.mp4 -vn -c:a pcm_u24le output.wav`)

Comment: `ffmpeg -i longfilename.mp4 -vn -c:a copy longfilenameoutput.{mp3|aac|ogg|wav}` is not working. Instead you could get the audio codec with `ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 longfilename.mp4`, split the input filename with something like `filename=$(basename "/path/to/file"); name=${filename%.*}; ext=${filename##*.}; echo "$ext"`, then simply construct an output filename. Note that this could produce incorrect extensions for the used codec, but works fine with aac, mp3, flac and probably others.

Comment: Yes it doesn't pick the extension automatically. The caller should actually do it. If run in bash then my example actually results in command `ffmpeg -i the-file.mp4 -vn -c:a copy output.mp3 output.aac output.ogg output.wav` which probably throws an error.

But if you pick the extension manually and the input has only one audio stream then it should work.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, only to mention that if your input audio is AAC you are better to choose output as M4A not AAC because choosing AAC will make output with wrong time and bad navigation though all contents are there but you can't navigate well.

Comment: @MílaMrvík According to `bash -x`; `...{mp3|aac|ogg|wav}` would result in `+ ffmpeg -i asdf.mkv -c:a copy 'output.{mp3'
bash: ogg: Command not found.
bash: wav}: Command not found.
bash: aac: Command not found.`, as bash interprets the pipe symbol `|` , ...well as pipe to a program, which it can't find.

`... {mp3,aac,ogg,wav}` on the other hand would output `+ ffmpeg -i asdf.mkv -vn -c:a copy output.mp3 output.aac output.ogg output.wav`.

Comment: @mashuptwice True. I confused it with comma. Sorry :)